# PHP/JavaScript How to show modal after submitting a form

Tags: javascript, php, forms, modal-dialog

I have a form with information about some people. Information is coming from a database, and next to each row is a button. When I press the button, modal should open and show only the information about that person. So if I have 5 people, there are also 5 buttons and each buttons should open a modal with information about that person.

My code is almost working. I don't know how to show a modal after pressing the button, because when I press the button the page reloads and the modal will start to show but it won't fully show becuase th page reload will prevent it. My code is working and the modal is showing the correct information, but the problem is that my page reloads after pressing the button,so it doesn't show my modal.

As far as I know I need to implement Ajax to my code but I am not sure how.

Here is my code:

https://github.com/luka3ska/Form

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Nobody can tell you what's wrong with code we can't see.  Please provide a [mcve] demonstrating the problem.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: Having said that... From the description it sounds *highly likely* that your button is posting a form, which reloads the page.  If the purpose of the button is only to update the client-side UI then change it so it's not a submit button for a form.

Comment: In JS, set up an event listener on the form with a callback function. When that event is triggered, [prevent the form from submitting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) (if you actually need a form), get the id for that form, make an [ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) to fetch the info from PHP and populate and show the modal.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am new to programming so it's a but hard to understand exactly what I need to do. I edited my post and uplouded my code to GitHub, so it might be a bit easier now to help me fix my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should try:

```
<button name="test" type="button" onclick="onClick()">Click</button>
```

**default** value of type is **submit**. And this triggers a refresh.
So the type must be "**button**"

Comment: It's better to set an even listener in JS, than adding it as an attribute on the HTML element. It's also better to set the event listener on the forms `submit`-event than the button. If you set it on the button, the form will still submit "normally" if the user hits the "enter"-key while having an input-element focused. It also makes more sense if you want to submit the form using JS for some reason. Then you don't need to involve the button at all.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a problem about **the event**, you must stop the default behavior of the button.

You can do that with event.preventDefault().

**In Javascript :**

```
document.getElementById("buttonId").addEventListener("click", function(event){
    event.preventDefault()
    // Ajax request here ...
});
```

**In JQuery :**

```
$("buttonId").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    // Ajax request here ...

});
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am new to programming so it's a but hard to understand exactly what I need to do. I edited my post and uplouded my code to  GitHub.

Comment: I think u need to add event here : 
`
  button.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const modal = document.querySelector(button.dataset.modalTarget)
    openModal(modal)
  })
})
`

Comment: You can read this doc to understand event concept in Javascript : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

Answer (score 0):

To extend on @Dumhuzy 's anwser and help you understand what's going on. Whenever you have a `<button>` within `<form>` that button will submit the form regardless of if it has the attribute `type="submit"` or not. Submitting a form will cause the page to reload.

```
<form action="">
    <button>Will reload the page</button>
    <button id="prevent">Will prevent reload</button>
</form>
```

To prevent the form from submitting you must prevent the default action with javascript.

```
document.getElementById("prevent").addEventListener("click", function(event){
    event.preventDefault()
});
```